# How to get response of event in publisher?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit and rabbitMQ in c#.

I send commands to consumer, get them in consumer and execute required tasks and try to send response to publisher.

```
using MyCompany.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MassTransit.Receiver
{
    public class RegisterCustomerConsumer : IConsumer<IRegisterCustomer>
    {       
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRegisterCustomer> context)
        {           
            IRegisterCustomer newCustomer = context.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("A new customer has signed up, it's time to register it in the command receiver. Details: ");
            Console.WriteLine(newCustomer.Address);
            Console.WriteLine(newCustomer.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(newCustomer.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(newCustomer.Preferred);

            context.Publish<ICustomerRegistered>(new
            {
                Address = newCustomer.Address,
                Id = newCustomer.Id,                
                RegisteredUtc = newCustomer.RegisteredUtc,
                Name = newCustomer.Name             
            });

            return Task.FromResult(context.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I find this sample code which properly get message and perform related task.
Author of topic added this comment:

`Note that we didn’t have to specify a queue name here as opposed to sending a command to a single queue. We’ll see that the queue names are only provided in the consumers. MassTransit will create the necessary queues in the background.`

Now, where will published response message and how to get this response in publisher?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like publisher should subscribe to `ICustomerRegistered` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, look at the request/response sample.

Also, review the documentation for the request client usage:

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html

Comment: Chris, I also linked to the same page. I believe the `Respond` call is missing there, I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the whole request/response sample in the [Github repository](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse).

To use request/response you need to use the request client as described in the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html).

On the request consumer, you need to use `context.Respond(...)` to send the response to your request client.

Hence that request/response requires you to use the receiver address. Publishing requests is not supported since it makes no sense, you need to get only one response, not an unknown number of responses. The response is also sent to the requestor, not published, for the same reason.